# Update multiple columns with GROUP_CONCAT not working as expected

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Help wanted fellas! I have a stored precedure that updates the columns of a calendar-style table from another one. The records of the second one should be stored in the calendar grouped according its date and individual, however I cannot achieve it in a single UPDATE sentence; I had to make these ugly series of column-by-column updates. If you have any idea, it will be appreciated. Code is below:

```
DECLARE thisYearMonth VARCHAR(7);
SET thisYearMonth = '2016-09';

UPDATE calendar CAL
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT checkinout.userid,
        checkinout.checktime,
        GROUP_CONCAT(checkinout.checktime) ORDER BY checkinout.id SEPARATOR ' | ') AS checktime
    FROM checkinout
    INNER JOIN calendar ON calendar.userid = checkinout.userid
    WHERE checkinout.userid = calendar.userid
        AND DATE(checktime) = CONCAT(thisYearMonth, '-', '01')
    GROUP BY userid
) CHK ON CHK.userid = CAL.userid 
SET CAL.day1 = CHK.checkstatus;

UPDATE calendar CAL
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT checkinout.userid,
        checkinout.checktime,
        GROUP_CONCAT(checkinout.checktime ORDER BY checkinout.id SEPARATOR ' | ') AS checktime
    FROM checkinout
    INNER JOIN calendar ON calendar.userid = checkinout.userid
    WHERE checkinout.userid = calendar.userid
        AND DATE(checktime) = CONCAT(thisYearMonth, '-', '02')
    GROUP BY userid
) CHK ON CHK.userid = CAL.userid 
SET CAL.day2 = CHK.checkstatus;
```

And so on until day n. The question is how do I make it work like just a single UPDATE that does not repeats in all remaning calendar rows the same value as the row "day1", i.e. day1 gets 10:00, day2 gets 10:00 and so on. Here's the code that generates this behavior:

```
UPDATE calendar CAL
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT checkinout.userid,
        checkinout.checktime,
        GROUP_CONCAT(checkinout.checktime) ORDER BY checkinout.id SEPARATOR ' | ') AS checktime
    FROM checkinout
    INNER JOIN calendar ON calendar.userid = checkinout.userid
    WHERE checkinout.userid = calendar.userid
        AND DATE(checktime) = CONCAT(thisYearMonth, '-', '01')
    GROUP BY userid
) CHK ON CHK.userid = CAL.userid 
SET CAL.day1 = CHK.checkstatus,
    CAL.day2 = CHK.checkstatus,
    CAL.day3 = CHK.checkstatus
...;
```

EDIT: According to Gordon Linoff this can be achieved using conditional aggregation, however it only brings one record per row and not all of the records that correspond to every userid on each day.

Like this:

[Results using conditional aggregation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QW6z.png)

Expected result:

[Result updating row by row individually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRPQk.png)

I'm posting this sample data in the code below for you to verify my results

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_checkinout;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_checkinout
 (`id` int, `userid` int, `checktime` datetime, `checkstatus` varchar(8));

INSERT INTO tmp_checkinout
 (`id`, `userid`, `checktime`, `checkstatus`)
VALUES
 (1 , 3, '2016-8-1 07:49:23', 'SHRP'),
 (2 , 2, '2016-8-1 08:01:40', 'SHRP'),
 (3 , 1, '2016-8-1 08:49:07', 'SHRP'),
 (4 , 5, '2016-8-1 09:14:19', 'LATE'),
 (5 , 3, '2016-8-2 07:48:06', 'SHRP'),
 (6 , 2, '2016-8-2 08:04:03', 'SHRP'),
 (7 , 4, '2016-8-2 08:04:12', 'SHRP'),
 (8 , 1, '2016-8-2 08:49:07', 'SHRP'),
 (9 , 5, '2016-8-2 09:10:31', 'TOLR'),
 (10, 3, '2016-8-2 10:40:16', 'EXTN'),
 (11, 3, '2016-8-3 07:48:32', 'SHRP'),
 (12, 2, '2016-8-3 08:05:34', 'SHRP'),
 (13, 4, '2016-8-3 08:12:23', 'LATE'),
 (14, 5, '2016-8-3 09:08:52', 'TOLR'),
 (15, 1, '2016-8-3 10:23:41', 'EXTN'),
 (16, 3, '2016-8-4 07:49:15', 'SHRP'),
 (17, 2, '2016-8-4 08:05:39', 'SHRP'),
 (18, 1, '2016-8-4 08:36:44', 'SHRP'),
 (19, 4, '2016-8-4 08:07:22', 'TOLR'),
 (20, 5, '2016-8-4 09:22:34', 'LATE'),
 (21, 3, '2016-8-5 07:51:42', 'SHRP'),
 (22, 4, '2016-8-5 08:11:33', 'LATE'),
 (23, 2, '2016-8-5 08:16:54', 'LATE'),
 (24, 1, '2016-8-5 08:53:20', 'SHRP'),
 (25, 5, '2016-8-5 09:26:02', 'LATE'),
 (26, 3, '2016-8-2 10:52:44', 'EXTN')
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_calendar;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_calendar
 (`userid` int, `day1` varchar(40), `day2` varchar(40), `day3` varchar(40), `day4` varchar(40), `day5` varchar(40));

INSERT INTO tmp_calendar
 (`userid`)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
```

Using Gordon Linoff's answer, this is the code that generates the results as described in picture 1:

```
UPDATE tmp_calendar AS cal
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT id, userid,
  CASE WHEN DAY(checktime) = 1 THEN CONCAT('ID:', id, ', ', checkstatus, ', ', checktime) ELSE NULL END AS timeandstatus_01,
  CASE WHEN DAY(checktime) = 2 THEN CONCAT('ID:', id, ', ', checkstatus, ', ', checktime) ELSE NULL END AS timeandstatus_02,
  CASE WHEN DAY(checktime) = 3 THEN CONCAT('ID:', id, ', ', checkstatus, ', ', checktime) ELSE NULL END AS timeandstatus_03,
  CASE WHEN DAY(checktime) = 4 THEN CONCAT('ID:', id, ', ', checkstatus, ', ', checktime) ELSE NULL END AS timeandstatus_04,
  CASE WHEN DAY(checktime) = 5 THEN CONCAT('ID:', id, ', ', checkstatus, ', ', checktime) ELSE NULL END AS timeandstatus_05
 FROM tmp_checkinout
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(checktime, '%Y-%m') = '2016-08'
 ORDER BY id ASC) AS chk ON chk.userid = cal.userid
SET cal.day1 = chk.timeandstatus_01,
 cal.day2 = chk.timeandstatus_02,
 cal.day3 = chk.timeandstatus_03,
 cal.day4 = chk.timeandstatus_04,
 cal.day5 = chk.timeandstatus_05
WHERE cal.userid = chk.userid;
```

Thanks for any pointer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need conditional aggregation in the subquery:

```
UPDATE calendar CAL INNER JOIN
       (SELECT ch.userid, ch.checktime,
               GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN DAY(checktime) = 01 THEN ch.checktime END ORDER BY ch.id SEPARATOR ' | ') AS checktime_01,
               GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN DAY(checktime) = 02 THEN ch.checktime END ORDER BY ch.id SEPARATOR ' | ') AS checktime_02,
               . . .
        FROM checkinout ch INNER JOIN
             calendar ca
             ON ca.userid = ch.userid
        WHERE date_format(checktime, '%Y-%m') = thisYearMonth
        GROUP BY userid
       ) CHK 
       ON CHK.userid = CAL.userid 
    SET CAL.day1 = CHK.checkstatus_01,
        CAL.day2 = CHK.checkstatus_02;
```

Comment: Sorry for answering late. I've been trying your solution but it doesn't work completely. I'll edit my question to expand what I've got until now...

Comment: @M.G. . . . You have to add in all the columns to update them.

Comment: Like in the select? Or in the set? Could you be more specific please?